# Array ngFor data missing / disappearing

Tags: javascript, angular, html-table, ngfor

I have following angular 6 component to add new users with a html table:

user-add.component.html

```
[...]
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let value of data.pos; let i = index">
        <td><input matInput [(ngModel)]="value.username" name="pos-{{i}}-username"></td>
        <td><input matInput [(ngModel)]="value.firstname" name="pos-{{i}}-firstname"></td>
        <td><input matInput [(ngModel)]="value.lastname" name="pos-{{i}}-lastname"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
[...]
```

user-add.component.ts

```
export class UserAddComponent {

    data: any = {
        pos: [{modell: '', user: '', asset: '', serial: ''}]
    };

    addPosition(){
        this.data.pos.push({modell: 'c', user: '', asset: '', serial: ''});
        console.log(this.data);
    }

    removePosition(pos){
        this.data.pos.splice([pos],1);
        console.log(this.data);
    }
```

When I click on a button calling the `addPosition()` button and filling all the input fields it is working without a problem.

The problem: When I click the remove button calling the function `removePosition(1)` to remove the second row it disappears as it should. But when I click on `addPosition` again to add a new row the data of the forst row 0 disappears from the html table. The console.log() in `addPosition` still outputs the correct data for pos 0 but it is not visible in the input fields for row 0.

Comment: `this.data.pos.splice([pos],1);` should be `this.data.pos.splice(pos,1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tracking issue. By looping over objects and using two-way binding on their properties, you make Angular lose its mind.

Provide it with a custom track by function, either like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let value of data.pos; let i = index; trackBy: value.id">
```

(ID = a unique identifier for each object)

Or like this

```html
<tr *ngFor="let value of data.pos; let i = index; trackBy: customTB">
```

```js
customTB(index, item) {
  return `${index}-${item.id}`;
}
```

(You can return what you want as long as its unique)

Comment: the second option is working great - thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

Are you testing on which browser? Because I tested your code and did not realize the symptoms that you specified.